# Process scheduler and thread scheduler

Tags: cpu, scheduler

I was reading through galvin chapters on process and thread 
Looking at processes , multiple processes are scheduled by the cpu scheduler or short term scheduler , after this comes the concept that a thread is a path of execution and a process can contain multiple threads .
Now i thought of a scenario , Suppose the cpu scheduler schedules a process for execution using round robin  algo , now suppose the scheduled process has 50 threads , now in this scenario how are the threads withing the same process scheduled and how does the context switch b/w threads , process happen 
Can plz sm one explain me the entire scenario in detals , i will be very thankfullll

Answer (score 0):

Process is a program in execution and its the job of the programmer to decide the number of threads in that process and how they would be scheduled.. it depends on which sequence he would like the program to run..
so as soon as the process is in running state it would run the thread that was scheduled to run by the programmer..
Even in case of threads running concurrently its the programmer who decides which threads can run concurrently and which cannot.. i hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Well that's not exactly detailed, but to answer the question, processes are devidied into timeslices, and the system allocates a certain number of timeslices per second to each process, and the scheduler does not have to be fair about who gets more timesclices, additionally, processes may chose how to use their timeslices, by dividing the slices they have been allocated further into frames know as threads. So in addition in your case toeach process being round robin, the individual processes would likely round robing their time slices.