# Python - OS Scheduler - Process and Thread - Theoretical Clarification

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, scheduling

I am a complete newbie to OS scheduling, So please bear with my ignorance.

I am trying to wrap my head around how the OS scheduling works with Python, to be specific, the Windows OS scheduling. I understand the process has its dedicated memory while a thread does not; also one process can have a single thread or multiple threads.

**My questions are as follows:**

1: If threads are the smallest component that OS can control, can I say the OS scheduler only schedules the thread, not the process?

2: I have come across [one StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093901/process-scheduler-and-thread-scheduler), and one comment suggests the OS scheduler only allocates a fraction of time to each process, and it is up to each process to allocate how long each thread runs?

Any suggestions will be helpful, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: My top suggestion?  Ignore that question/comment and wipe it from your brain.

Comment: Hey @MartinJames, haha ok I will. Would you kindly elaborate on my first question? Thank you so much!